# Storing Sax parser data in Array List as Hashmap

Tags: java, android, arrays, date, arraylist

I am having trouble storing data in Arraylist of Hashmap which is parsed from a local xml file.

First of all, here is my xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<organization>
                <employee>
                                <title>Harry0</title>
                                <link>Smith0</link>
                                <date>hs0</date>
                                <salary>200000-0</salary>
                </employee>

                <employee>
                                <title>Harry1</title>
                                <link>Smith1</link>
                                <date>hs1</date>
                                <salary>300000-1</salary>
                </employee>

                 <employee>
                                <title>Harry2</title>
                                <link>Smith2</link>
                                <date>hs2</date>
                                <salary>300000-2</salary>
                </employee>
</organization>
```

I want to store each pair of `title`, `link` and `date` in Hashmap and then put it inside array list of Hashmap.

I am using SAX parser but I couldn't be able to achieve what I want to do,

Here is my code for declaring a Hashmap and ArrayList of Hashmaps,

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> xml_Array = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    HashMap<String, String> keyValuePair = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Now What I did is,

```
@Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
                    startElement = localName;       
    }


    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
            elementValue = new String(ch, start, length);
    }


    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String endElement, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        super.endElement(uri, endElement, qName);

        if (startElement == endElement){
            inElements = true;
        }

        if (inElements == true){
            if (endElement == "title"){
                keyValuePair.put("title", elementValue);
                }
            else if (endElement == "link"){
                keyValuePair.put("link", elementValue);
                }
            else if (endElement == "date"){
                keyValuePair.put("date", elementValue);
                }
            inElements = false;
        }

        xml_Array.add(keyValuePair);
    }


    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        super.endDocument();

        Log.e("test",xml_Array + "");
    }
```

In `endElement` method of Sax Parser, I checked if the element is either `title`, `date` or `link` and then put its data in a hashmap and eventually add it inside array list, but the data is being overridden in arraylist instead of appending,

Here is my output from Logcat,

`[{date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2}]`

What the only last employee details are added in arraylist so many times ? and why the employee details of first two employees are not showing up ? 
What Am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: http://simple.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only create one HashMap instance

```
HashMap<String, String> keyValuePair = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Then you keep adding this same instance to the list. That why all the maps in the list are the same instance.

You have to call `keyValuePair = new HashMap<String, String>();` before each time you initialize a new map to be added to the list.

Comment: Thank you it works, but there is a new issue. Instead of adding it like this, {date=hs2, title=Harry2, link=Smith2} , it is adding each key/value pair in new curly braces like this, [{title=Harry0}, {link=Smith0}, {date=hs0}, {title=Harry1}, {link=Smith1}, {date=hs1}, {title=Harry2}, {link=Smith2}, {date=hs2}]

Comment: @Riley Willow you should create a new HashMap in the right place, which is before parsing the xml of a new employee.